# how do I create/format a .txt file so that eclipse/java can read it?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, text

I am doing an exercise in the text book and it calls for me to use a file called test.txt.  So I created the information that I needed and saved it as test.txt.  I keep getting errors when I try to use the inFile.  My question is does the .txt file have to be formatted in a certain way so the eclipse can read it?  I am doing a student test average file.  File asks for firstName, lastName, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5 which I put in the file, but it is not reading it.  Do I have to tab between each item (using MSWord) or is a space sufficient?  Can eclipse not read a file that was created in MSWord?  if not should I create this file in notepad?

I wrote it in MSWord saved as test.txt, when that didn't work I edited the file in notepad and saved it that way, still not reading it.  Which then made me question if it was the format of the file.  First I tried the firstName (tab)lastName(tab)test1(tab)...etc.  Then I went back and changed it to firstName(space)lastName(space)test1(space) neither format was read.

package chapter3;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StudentGrade {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

    //declare and initialize the variables
    double test1, test2, test3, test4, test5;
    double average;

    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader ("C:\\test.txt"));

    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("C:\\testavg.out");

    firstName = inFile.next();
    lastName = inFile.next();

    outFile.println("Student Name: " + firstName + "" + lastName);

    test1 = inFile.nextDouble();
    test2 = inFile.nextDouble();
    test3 = inFile.nextDouble();
    test4 = inFile.nextDouble();
    test5 = inFile.nextDouble();

    outFile.printf("Test Scores:  %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2 %n", test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);

    average = (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5);
    outFile.printf("Average test score: %5.2f %n", average);

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();



}
```

}

I just need it to read the file and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  The code above is from the textbook and neither the teacher nor the book provided the test.txt file that I need.

Comment: Do you need to read it or also write it to a different file?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Also just to let you know, except where the file is located the code is word for word from the text book.

Comment: Can you post the actual question? And also include the .txt file

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I just figured it out... I had to change some of the lines int their text and do the printf line by line instead of have it like they did.  I had to do it like this. outFile.printf("Test Score 1:  %5.2f,test1);  instead of the the line of code that read:outFile.printf("Test Scores:  %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2 %n", test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);  then it worked perfectly

Comment: Sorry for wasting every ones time.  I would think that what was written in the text book would have been correct and worked

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Word. Just use any plaintext editor, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

just create a txt file with data as below and place it in "C:\test.txt"

```
firstname
lastname
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

Try and learn how a scanner works